# Categorical Koszul duality

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, duality-theorems, derived-categories

Consider a (small idempotent closed) dg categories C over K. I am interested in the weak dual $C^{\vee}=Fun^{ex}(C, Perf  K)$ and when the functor
$C \rightarrow (C^{\vee})^{\vee}$ is an quasi-equivalence, which is a kind of categorical Koszul duality.

This functor is an equivalence if C is a dualizable object in the symmetric monoidal category of (small idempotent closed) dg categories C over K, which is precisely when C is smooth and proper. It is also an equivalence if
$C= D^b Coh(X)$ for a proper scheme $X$ by
https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7164.

Question: What are some other examples? Is there a general criterion for when this reflexitivity is true?

References would be appreciated as well. I am aware of https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5934 but this paper seems to study only the class of underived categories, where the situation is quite different as the authors point out.